# MPAndroidChart PieChart - set data from plain text input

Tags: android, pie-chart, mpandroidchart

I'm making an app that I can input name and money and calculate together. Example i input like this in plain text

```
User 1 = $520    
User 2 = $241 
User 3 = $253
User 4 = $704

Total = $1718
```

and here are the id i declared for my plain texts

```
name1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editName1);
name2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editName2);
name3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editName3);
name4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editName4);

money1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editMoney1);
money2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editMoney2);
money3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editMoney3);
money4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editMoney4);
```

but how can I set the data from plain text to `PieGraph`?

Answer (score 0):

- Convert the text to numbers (integer, float, ...)
- Add them like this:

  ```
  float number1 = ...; // parse your EditText input here
  // other numbers ...

  ArrayList<Entry> vals = new ArrayList<Entry>();
  vals.add(new Entry(number1, 0));
  vals.add(new Entry(number2, 1));
  vals.add(new Entry(number3, 2));
  vals.add(new Entry(number4, 3));

  String[] xVals = new String[] { "User1", "User2", "User3", "User4" };

  PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(vals, "User Values");
  PieData data = new PieData(xVals, dataSet);

  pieChart.setData(data);
  // refresh
  pieChart.invalidate();
  ```

Also, the [example project](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/tree/master/MPChartExample) shows numerous use cases of how data can be added to the charts, you might wanna check it out.

Furthermore, the [documentation](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki) is pretty good and also gives examples and instructions on how to add data.

Comment: thanks but the code you provided gives me an error `"Entry (float, int) in Entry cannot be applied to (android.widget.EditText, int)`. i was not able to find an example about adding data from plain text.

Comment: You can of course not set an EditText as an entry. You need to transform the value that is inside the EditText to a float, and set that to the entry as I show in the above example.

Comment: i putted the EditText entry on `setOnClickListener` but a problem is it can't read the code inside  `setOnClickListener` -> `onClick` methods and it says `cannot resolve symbol...`. here is my source http://pastebin.com/zEdEH1dA